# Does Indy use some kind of cooperative multitasking on XP, and if so, is there a way to switch to other connections?

Tags: delphi, indy

I have a web server that runs off of Indy's TIdTCPServer component. I have several requests coming in at once that need to be synchronised so each requests gets handled after the previous was sent. This is done using a mutex. On Vista and Win7 this works great but on XP it seems the wait on the mutex also hangs other connections. It times out after 5 seconds so it'll still continue, but my app is very time sensitive.

I assume it goes like this on XP:

Connection 1:

- Parse request
- Try to acquire mutex
- Success
- Do stuff
- Reply -> Indy uses this opportunity to switch threads

Connection 2:

- Parse request
- Try to acquire mutex
- Fail with time out
- Return "sorry, time out" -> Indy switches back to Connection 1

Connection 1:

- Release mutex

If Indy uses cooperative multitasking like this, I'll have to do something else. Does anyone know if on XP it does use cooperative multitasking?

*EDIT:*

So, I'm seeing in IdYarn that the yarn is a completely empty object now. Still, the question stands about cooperative multitasking.

Comment: How are you ensuring order and prioritizing the earliest connections?

Comment: Doh! I got my jargon messed up. Yes, it's preemptive multitasking. Regardless, that's not the issue. Indy leaves the scheduling up to the OS. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every connection in a TIdTCPServer runs in its own worker thread.  The OS, not Indy, controls task switching between threads. If one thread successfully locks the mutex, no other thread can enter the lock until the first thread unlocks it. That is Mutithreaded Programming 101, on any OS version. That behavior is not specific to Indy. What you outlined is how it is supposed to behave. If Vista/Win7 is not behaving that way, then you have a problem.

Comment: In coop multitasking, the "threads" are actually 1 thread. The switching occurs at set points, in win16 it was, among others, GetMessage. Since it's only 1 thread, the mutex won't be released until the acquire of "thread" 2 times out. The acquire wouldn't time out if "thread" 2 can simply grab it after "thread" 1 is done with it. In the coop case, thread 2 won't run until thread 1 calls a coop call, which it won't until the acquire times out. In any case, if they all have their own...

Comment: OS threads, this can't be the issue, but XP behaves differently than Vista/7 nonetheless. I guess I'll figure it out...

Comment: Where does the idea of "yarns" in Indy belong? It reminds me of fibers, which is coop multitasking. That's why I dared to ask in the first place.

Comment: @DDS: what you describe for "coop multitasking" is implemented in Windows using fibers, where the application controls switching between fibers, and multiple fibers can run inside a single thread. Indy does not implement fibers, only plain threads (we tried to implement fibers once, in Indy's companion SuperCore package, but it did not work out very well so it was abandoned). Multiple fibers running in the same thread can enter a locked mutex at the same time, as the lock is tied to the thread.  It is not possible for multiple threads to enter the same lock at the same time.

Comment: @DDS: the idea of "yarns" in Indy 10 came about from the effort to decouple server-side connections from threads, knowing that we wanted to implement support for more advanced threading models (fibers, etc), where a connection could jump from one thread to another as needed.  In Indy 9 and earlier, connections belonged to `TIdPeerThread`, which was a `TThread` descendant.  In Indy 10, connections belong to `TIdContext`, which is a standalone class that runs in a thread but is not a thread itself. The yarn model still exists in Indy, but we still use only plain threads for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Actually XP may very well be a cooperative/preemptive hybrid multitasker. Under a true preemptive multitasker you can't have a process that dominates the processor as the preemptive task switcher won't allow it to. Under a cooperative multitasker, you can have a process that can dominate the processor which will bring down such a system. In XP we have processes which can dominate the processor up to 99 percent of the time but usually not 100 percent of the time. This behavior clearly shows that XP is a cooperative/preemptive multitakser. XP allows the process to decide on how long it will run and then pass control back to the system up to a certain point. If the process tries to go beyond that point, then XP will use it's preemptive capabilites to limit this.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, Indy threads (TIdYarn) let the operating system do the scheduling (since they are OS threads).

The scenario that you describe can still happen with preemptive multi-tasking. Using a locking mutex can help the situation, but it's not the entire solution.

First, ensure that your mutex locking is the first thing in the OnExecute. This will keep the other threads from taking processor time away while the thread that's at the front of the queue is being processed.

You state that your application is time sensitive. If by this you mean that you expect a short response time for each request, then you need to do something to enforce FIFO (First In First Out), which is the second part of the solution.

The scheme that you describe doesn't account for this. If thread A has the mutex lock, and meanwhile threads B through Z show up waiting for the lock, thread B isn't guaranteed to get the lock next. It could be Z that gets the lock next. In fact, B could get the lock last, and have timed out before then.

There were quite a [few improvements in Vista](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.02.vistakernel.aspx) that made the scheduling more fair between threads of equal priority. The effect on Windows XP would be compounded if your threads are running at lower priority. Perhaps this is what you're seeing, in combination with the fact that you have no FIFO.

I would expect timeouts on individual threads if there are a lot of threads waiting and there is no FIFO implemented.

Comment: There's only 5 threads waiting at most and the request should be handled in milliseconds, and the Acquire wait is 5 seconds, so that's not the issue. I think what's going on is that on XP the "Do stuff" is taking long due to some other problem. There's an event somewhere that also waits for the same 5 seconds, so this is why the two got confused. I changed the Acquire to 25 seconds, but the response time was still only 5 seconds. Also, FIFO isn't needed, it's the response order only that matters, and it's not related to the request time/order.

Comment: It might not be the issue yet. Sorry you didn't find my answer helpful at all and you knew this and considered it already. Maybe it's time to post some code then. :)